# What is the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in the expansion of $ \prod \limits_{n=1}^{20} (x+n^2)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

How could we find the coefficient of $x^{19}$ in the expansion of $ \prod \limits_{n=1}^{20} (x+n^2)$?

Comment: Try to answer the question for $20$ and $19$ replaced by something much smaller, like $3$ and $2$. Then try $4$ and $3$ and then $5$ and $4$. Then make a guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Vieta's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), noting that your polynomial has roots $x_k = -k^2$ for $k$ from 1 to 20.

Answer (score 6):

$$
\prod \limits_{i=1}^d (x + a_i) = x^d + \Big(\sum_i a_i \Big) x^{d-1} + \Big( \sum_{i < j} a_i a_j \Big) x^2 + \Big( \sum_{i < j < k} a_i a_j a_k \Big) x^3 + \cdots,
$$
so the coefficient of $x^{d-1}$ in $\prod \limits_{i=1}^d (x + a_i)$ is $\sum \limits_{i=1}^d a_i$. In your case, the answer is $\sum \limits_{i=1}^{20} i^2 = \cdots$.

---

*Note:* If you are interested in the general term, the coefficient of $t^{\rm th}$ is given by the ["elementary symmetric polynomial"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial)
$$
\sum_{i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_t} a_{i_1} a_{i_2} \cdots a_{i_t}. 
$$

Comment: Could you please add few more terms of $\prod \limits_{i=1}^d (x + a_i) = x^d + \Big(\sum \limits_{i=1}^d a_i \Big) x^{d-1} + \Big( \sum \limits_{i < j} a_i a_j \Big) x^2 + \cdots,$ ? I am not able to spot the pattern.

Comment: Also, how exactly $\Big( \sum \limits_{i < j} a_i a_j \Big)$ working here ?

Comment: @MaX: roughly, take all $k$-subsets of the $a_k$, multiply all the members of those subsets, and then add up those products.

Comment: @MaX You have to take pairs of numbers, like: {a_1, a_2}, {a_1, a_3}, {a_1, a_4}, ...,{a_1, a_n}, {a_2, a_3}, {a_2, a_4}, ..., {a_2, a_n}, ..., {a_{n-1}, a_n}. Multiply each pair and all those up to get a big sum. For a general k-th term, you should generalize this as J.M. describes.